# Update APK from local repository - Xamarin.Forms (Android)

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I'm developing the actualization system of my app. All the workspace running in a local enviroment, the server, the data base, and every app are runing locally so I thought the best way of actualizated all the mobile apps of the company at the same time it was by sharing the .apk on a local shared folder on the server so every one have accese to the file. The `OnStart()` method of the `App.xaml.cs` search into the reposiroty if there is an apk version higher than the actual one, if it is, it should download the file and then run it to intall the app.

So the firt step to achive it, is accesse to the repository, download the file and save it into the device.

So far I can download images from the web and save them on the local foldel I want to by using dependency services but I can't download them form a local directory, **how can I do that?**

This is my service (Android):

```
public void DownloadFile(string url,string pathToNewFolder) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToNewFolder);

    try {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted+=new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
        string pathToNewFile = Path.Combine(pathToNewFolder,"example.jpg");
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url),pathToNewFile);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        if(OnFileDownloaded!=null)
            OnFileDownloaded.Invoke(this,new DownloadEventArgs(false));
    }
}
```

If I use this call, it works:

```
downloader.DownloadFile("https://picsum.photos/200/300", @"/sdcard");
```

But I need to use something like:

```
downloader.DownloadFile(@"\\192.168.0.15\images\example.jpg", @"/sdcard");
```

**It is there a `WebClient` for a local enviroment?**

I used this blog for create my the dependency services: [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-download-files-in-xamarin-forms/).
Also I tried use a nuget package (it didn't work): [link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/xamarin-forms-creating-update-system-without-google-play-tofanelli/)

Is it the better way to solve my problem?

Comment: What do you mean with "local" environment. Is it a SMB/CIFS share? WebDAV? FTP? Something else?

Comment: Sorry I'm junior I don't know what those terms mean. I have evething running on the same network wifi, the server the all devices and the database

Comment: But the server, it needs to use some kind of protocol. If it is not a Web Server, what is it then? WebClient mainly understands normal HTTP requests. Not some arbitrary protocol that you dream up or run on your local servers. If it is a network drive, it is likely SMB/CIFS, WebClient doesn't understand that and won't download files from there, you need a different client to get such files.

Comment: Ok I get it, I need a substitute to 'WebClient' and the 'DownloadFileAsync' function. Do you know other client that can do that?

Comment: Easiest for you would be to spin up a small web server somewhere. It can be hosted on anything really and serve the files through that. I bet your organization already has some infrastructure for that. Leverage your IT admins help.

There seems to be some efforts for SMB like SMBLibrary: https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary I have no experience with those.

Comment: Im afraid I am the IT admin on my organization but thanks I will investigate the posibility of make a new service to download the file from the server ... Thank u